# Adding a wrapper to the youtube embed automatically?

Tags: youtube, oembed

With newer versions of WordPress, YouTube auto oEmbeds. On this particular site I am working on, I need a unique `div` wrapper around the embedded `iframe`. I had a look in my `functions.php` but couldn't see anything related to YouTube. Where would I find the code I need to add my extra html?

Comment: I like this question but yes, needs expansion.

Answer (score 4):

Make a [custom plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/pluginception/) for your site, put this code in it.

```
add_filter('oembed_dataparse','oembed_youtube_add_wrapper',10,3);
function oembed_youtube_add_wrapper($return, $data, $url) {
    if ($data->provider_name == 'YouTube') {
        return "<div class='whatever'>{$return}</div>";
    } else {
        return $return;
    }
}
```

> **Note:** The filter runs when the data is gathered from the oembed provider. So, if you already embedded the post, and the embed data is cached, this won't modify it.

Comment: Confirm that this works.

Comment: *Edit* – I'm not sure if this just works out of the box. Either I just got a heavy caching problem or the filter (which runs at the end of `WP_OEmbed`s constructor in core) only runs for fresh posts. Can't backtrace that one. @Otto Any hints?

Comment: The filter runs when the data is gathered from the oembed provider. So, it you already embedded the post, and the embed data is cached, this won't modify it.

Comment: Thanks, but *where* is that cached?

Comment: The info from oembeds is saved as post-meta.

Comment: Post meta for an `attachment`? And under which `meta_key`? I just checked a local database and can't find anything there. I also couldn't find anything related to post meta save mechanisms when it comes to `\WP_oEmbed` and related functions. Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: It's post meta for the post, not in an attachment. The key is _oembed_hash, where hash is the MD5 hash of the URL and the attributes involved. Look at class-wp-embed.php, line 180 or thereabouts.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I found the `oembed_dataparse` filter pretty fiddly to use; sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't; and when used in conjunction with custom TinyMCE instances, it seems as though the added wrapper was hard-baked into the content rather than added via the filter at output.

I found the `embed_oembed_html` filter much more reliable and works every time:

```
function vnmFunctionality_embedWrapper($html, $url, $attr, $post_id) {
    return '<div class="embedwrapper">' . $html . '</div>';
}

add_filter('embed_oembed_html', 'vnmFunctionality_embedWrapper', 10, 4);
```

Note that this will wrap *all* oEmbeds. If you wanted to target YouTube specifically:

```
function vnmFunctionality_embedWrapper($html, $url, $attr, $post_id) {

    if (strpos($html, 'youtube') !== false) {
        return '<div class="youtubewrapper">' . $html . '</div>';
    }

    return $html;
}
```

Comment: Your answer works as well … Personally I'd prefer to target providers by _name_ then my a _guess_ on the url. Still +1 for the alternative. If you are **unsure if it works:** just put an `exit` on the other answers filter callback and you will see it working.

Comment: @kaiser Fair point; I hadn't actually analysed the parameters here in much detail; much like the OP, I only needed it to work for YouTube, and I knew what the input was going to be. But this will fall over when presented with shortened URLs and such.

Comment: Just have the problem that I can't get any output there as well … as live goes :P